# How does IIS HTTP compression handle dynamic types versus static types?

Tags: iis, web-config, http-compression

The sample configuration listed in Microsoft's documentation of the IIS [system.webServer/httpCompression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) configuration setting is as follows:

```xml
<httpCompression
      directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
   <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
   <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
   </dynamicTypes>
   <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
   </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

What I'm not understanding is why their list of dynamic and static types are identical. Wouldn't you want a given MIME type to be deterministically registered as either dynamic *or* static, not both?

In the above example, I can't tell if `application/javascript` responses will be treated as dynamic or static because it's listed under both settings. Can someone shed some light on how this works?

Comment: It really depends on the request URL that generates the response. Requests on static files triggers static compression. Read the article again and it covers that already.

Comment: @LexLi I understand that, but that still leaves my core question in the second half of my post unanswered. Why are these two lists of mime types identical?

Comment: Why cannot they be the same? Responses on .js can be JavaScript, and responses generated by ASP.NET or PHP can also be JavaScript.

Comment: I think I’m starting to understand, but what I’m still not getting is how/where IIS elsewhere determines that a response is dynamic or static to begin with.

Comment: That’s because you need to dig further into IIS via tools like failed request tracing. Static files are handled by a dedicate IIS component so static responses are easy to tell. Other responses are likely to be dynamic.

Comment: Ok thank you, I’ll do some more digging. If you have a recommended book or link to information on this topic, I’d greatly appreciate the tip.

Comment: You might get some hints from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x